# Too many connections are used for insert data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am aksing about too many connections in mysql server and phpmyadmin, as data speed per hour ~1000 from source in my database. When I TOP on server, mysqld shows 100-145% cpu utilization also lots of php threads are running there , as data insertion through php script. My question is, is there any mechanism through which connections are not overflow and mysql server utilize cpu as low as possible. since I am using VPS server but it is not so effective to use another application on vps, because mysql server takes 100% cpu. Sometime phpmyadmin crashes and shows some folk error. I have read **query cache** mechanism, but it is used for caching same select queries, should i use this for insert or is there any other optimal solution kind of **queue mechanism**. Also, i can't say about on which time insert data speed is low or high, if it knows then i can try queue mechanism. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @GordonM: data insert continuously in database through php script, mysql server use 100% cpu utilization on vps server

Answer (score 1):

Check your codes and see if you have something like

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) // basicly long loop with inserts
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (id, value) VALUES ({$i}, 100)");
```

This should be altered to something like

```
$arr_values = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
    $arr_values[] = "({$i}, 100)";

$str_values = implode(', ', $arr_values);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (id, value) VALUES {$str_values}");
```

Basicly be aware of unneeded queries in your code.

Comment: Is memcache relevant for this problem? As it is working like server and client

Comment: i don't find any way yet to solve database exceed usage, i am using insert query per second ~20 but doesn't find any cache mechanism for insert which writes data to database and handle usage of less mysql connections

Answer (score 0):

You should get a basic idea about **"QUERY CACHE"** from the following link
    [mysql_query cache](http://www.docplanet.org/mysql/mysql-query-cache-in-depth/)

Comment: Query cache is not my concern , since data is insert via some source continuously instead of select some data from database..